# Inserting data when no record is found else update the previous record with last inserted ID using PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have 2 tables properties as parent table and sale_listings as a child.
I want, programmatically, to insert or update sale listing record into 
sale_listings table while properties table's data is inserted.

If the previous record is found in sale_listings table then update the record
else insert new sale listing record.

Both tables data are successfully inserted without checking the previous 
records in the sale_listing(child table).

When I try to check the previous record in sale_listing using rowCount,
the application does not affect any row at all.

I want to know how I can achieve this with PHP-Mysql?

Below is the source code:

```
//Assign Property Values
$property_type = isset($_POST["property_type"] ) ? $_POST["property_type"]: '';
$agent = isset($_POST["agent"] ) ? $_POST["agent"]: '';
$suburb = isset($_POST["suburb"] ) ? $_POST["suburb"]: '';
$street_no = isset($_POST["street_no"] ) ? $_POST["street_no"]: '';
$street_name = isset($_POST["street_name"] ) ? $_POST["street_name"]: '';
$desc = isset($_POST["desc"] ) ? $_POST["desc"]: '';             
$property_status = isset($_POST["property_status"] ) ? $_POST["property_status"]: '';
$num_bathrooms = isset($_POST["num_bathrooms"] ) ? $_POST["num_bathrooms"]: '';
$num_beds = isset($_POST["num_beds"] ) ? $_POST["num_beds"]: '';
$num_garages = isset($_POST["num_garages"] ) ? $_POST["num_garages"]: '';
$num_lounges = isset($_POST["num_lounges"] ) ? $_POST["num_lounges"]: '';
$air_con = isset($_POST["air_con"] ) ? $_POST["air_con"]: '';
$pool = isset($_POST["pool"] ) ? $_POST["pool"]: '';
$cottage = isset($_POST["cottage"] ) ? $_POST["cottage"]: '';
$price = isset($_POST["price"] ) ? $_POST["price"]: '';

if((!empty($agent)) || (!empty($suburb)) || (!empty($property_type)) || 
  (!empty($street_no)) || (!empty($street_name)) ||(!empty($desc)) || 
  (!empty($property_status)) || (!empty($num_bathrooms)) || 
  (!empty($num_beds)) || (!empty($num_garages)) || (!empty($num_lounges)) || 
  (!empty($air_con)) || (!empty($pool)) || (!empty($cottage)) || 
  (!empty($price))){

    //Insert data into Properties table
    $query = "INSERT INTO properties (agent_id, suburb_id, property_type, 
    property_status, street_no, street_name, property_desc, num_bathrooms, 
    num_beds, num_garages, num_lounges, air_con, pool, cottage, price)
    VALUES('$agent', '$suburb', '$property_type', '$property_status', 
    '$street_no', '$street_name', '$desc', '$num_bathrooms', '$num_beds', 
    '$num_garages', '$num_lounges', '$air_con', '$pool', '$cottage', 
    '$price')";

     $row_count = $this->conn->exec($query);

    //Retrieve the last inserted Property ID
    $last_insert_property_id = $this->conn->lastInsertId(); 

    if($row_count){
        $query = "UPDATE suburbs SET total_properties = total_properties + 1
                  WHERE suburb_id = '$suburb'";
        $row_count = $this->conn->exec($query);

        //Check if the last inserted property ID exists   
        if($last_insert_property_id){

        //If the last property_id exists, make it equal to property ID                                
        $property_id = $last_insert_property_id;

        //Check if previous sale listing exist
        $query_sel = "SELECT sale_listing_id, property_id, 
        sale_listing_amount, discount_percent, total_listing
        FROM sale_listings"; 

        $result = $this->conn->query($query_sel); 

        if($result->rowCount() > 0){
            $query = "UPDATE sale_listings SET total_listing = total_listing + 1             WHERE property_id = '$property_id'";
            $row_count = $this->conn->exec($query);
        }else{
            $sale_amount = 65;
            $discount = 0;
            $total_listing = 1;

            $sql = "INSERT INTO sale_listings (property_id, 
                    sale_listing_amount, discount_percent, total_listing)
                    VALUES('$property_id', '$sale_amount', '$discount', 
                    '$total_listing')";
            $row_count = $this->conn->exec($sql);
            }                           

       }else{
            echo("Unable to insert or update record!"); 
          }
        }

        return $row_count;
    }
```

Comment: Both update and insert work. I should have added different column to do the checking due to newly generated property id that didn't update. As suggested Sven to change different column and eventually I did. In this case, I used suburb_id to do the checking because suburb_id will have more than one occurrence in properties but property_id won't. Solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss a very essential part of your `UPDATE` query, right now your update query would update **all** records in your table instead, you should add a `WHERE` statement so only the field you want gets updated. For example:

```
UPDATE sale_listings 
       SET total_listing = total_listing+1 
       WHERE sale_listing_id = 'current_sale_listing_id'
```

I also miss the where statement in your select to check if the previous listing exists, so your row count would always be incorrect. This should be:

```
SELECT sale_listing_id, property_id, 
        sale_listing_amount, discount_percent, total_listing
        FROM sale_listings WHERE property_id = 'last_property_id'
```

Also look into [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php), it is never a good idea to insert variables directly into your query.

You use the property_id to check/update the sale listings, however each time a new property is listed it will generate a new, unique id. This causes your insert to always create a new property instead of updating the old one because the newly generated ID will never be in the sale listings. I would recommend to add the address to the sale listing and perform the `where` clause on this column/these columns to update the sale listings.

Comment: Thank for the insight Sven. I added where clause with last_property_id but the problem stands still.

Comment: @LawrenceBosumbe, have you verified that the `$property_id` is what you expect it to be and what the row count is which is returned by PHP? (this way you know if it fails there or it fails on your update statement

Comment: I did property_id checking as you suggested. It now inserts new records but when I try to insert the same data, it does not update. Do you have anything in mind or can I shuffle the code little bit? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have added some more information to my answer, if anything is unclear feel free to ask @LawrenceBosumbe

Comment: you're 100% correct and helpful. Both update and insert work. Thanks. May God bless you!.

Comment: OK. I'll do that.